# setuid() failing - operation not permitted

Tags: c, linux, uid, setuid

> changeIDs() is trying to use setuid() to change the effective user id
>   but it always errors out and I'm not sure why.

I have two users on computer. user is an admin with UID of 1000. The other standard user, user 2, has a UID of 1001.

I want to use this program to set user2's effective UID to that of user1 (1000). Why does setuid() keep erroring?

I made sure to run chmod u+s on the program executable as well and it still fails.

**rror with setuid() - errno : Operation not permitted**

*Also, do you know why the E in cut off in my perror strings?*

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <getopt.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <errno.h>

void getArguments(int argc, char **argv);
void displayIDs();
void changeID(int userid);



int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    getArguments(argc, argv);

    return 0;
}



/*
 * The program accepts an option of “c” followed by a numeric user id.
 * When executing the program with the c option followed by a user id,
 * the system displays the real, effective, and saved set user id,
 * then attempts to change the effective user id to the numeric user
 * id passed into the application, and then displays the real,
 * effective, and saved set user id. (20 pts)
 */
void changeID(int userid)
{
    printf("Original IDs:\n==================\n");
    displayIDs();

    uid_t newid = (uid_t)userid;

    //pass the id var as references as outlined in the setuid() man pages
    //error check, fail returns -1
    /*
    if(setresuid(&newid, &newid, &newid) == -1)
    {
        perror("Error with setuid() - errno " + errno);
    }
    */


    if(setuid(&newid) == -1)
    {
        perror("Error with setuid() - errno " + errno);
    }


    printf("\n(Attempted) Changed IDs:\n==================\n");
    displayIDs();
}



/*
 * The program accepts an option of “g.”
 * When executing the program with the g option,
 * the system displays the real, effective,
 * and saved set user id. (10 pts)
 */
void displayIDs()
{
    uid_t ruid;//real user id
    uid_t euid;//effective user id
    uid_t suid;//saved set id

    //pass the id vars as references as outlined in the getresuid() man pages
    //error check, fail returns -1
    if ( getresuid(&ruid, &euid, &suid) == -1)
    {
        perror("Error with getresuid() - errno " + errno);
    }

    printf("Real User ID: %d\n", ruid);
    printf("Effective User ID: %d\n", euid);
    printf("Saved Set User ID: %d\n", suid);
}



//get the arguments from the command line and pass it into the program, calling the right function
void getArguments(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int option = 0;

    while ((option = getopt(argc, argv, "gc:")) != -1)
    {

        switch (option)
        {
             case 'g' :
                 displayIDs();
                 break;
             case 'c' :
                 changeID(optarg);
                 break;
             case '?' :
                 printf("Invalid argument\n");
                 break;
             default:
                 printf("Invalid - no argument (g or c)\n");
                 break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you're misunderstanding what `setuid` does - it doesn't change the uid of a user on the system.  It changes the user id of the current process, to make it as thought it were being run by a different user.  Normally, only root can do this.

Answer (score 2):

> **rror with setuid() - errno : Operation not permitted**
>
> *Also, do you know why the E in cut off in my perror strings?*

This is because you pass `perror()` `"Error with setuid() - errno " + errno`, which is equivalent to `&"Error with setuid() - errno "[errno]`, which is (since `errno` equals 1) equal to the address of the second `char` of the string.
You seem to be used to a language with a concatenation operator `+`, which is not the case in C.

Answer (score 1):

It fails because neither the effective user ID you're going to set is 0(root) nor the effective Id is identical to the ID you expected.

Below comes from `setuid(2)`:

> The setuid() function sets the real and effective user IDs and the
>   saved
>        set-user-ID of the current process to the specified value.  The setuid()
>        function is permitted if the effective user ID is that of the super user,
>        or if the specified user ID is the same as the effective user ID.  If
>        not, but the specified user ID is the same as the real user ID, setuid()
>        will set the effective user ID to the real user ID.