# Fail to seteuid in java by calling JNI

Tags: java, java-native-interface, setuid

My app need to run as none-root user but need to switch to other user to execute some commands.

I tried to:

1. write a JNI,

   ```
   JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_SetUIDJNI_setuid(JNIEnv *env, jobject thisObj,jstring uname) {
       const char *name = jstringTostring(env,uname);
       int pid;
       struct passwd *p;
       show_ids();
       if ((p = getpwnam(name)) == NULL) {
           perror(name);
           exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
       }
       pid = (int) p->pw_uid;
       printf("pid=%d\n",pid);
       if (seteuid (pid) < 0) {
           perror ("setuid");
           exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
       }
       show_ids();
   }
   ```
2. build it as **root** and **chmod u+s**

   ```
   -rwsr-xr-x 1 root root  76155 Aug  7 16:56 libsetuid.so*
   ```
3. call it in java

   ```
   api = new SetUIDJNI();  // invoke the native method
   api.setuid("slurm");
   ```

But if run it as none-root, it does not work

```
/opt/jdk1.8/jre/bin/java -Djava.library.path=../jni HelloJNI
 The real user ID is: 1000
 The effective user ID is :1000   <= which expected is 0
 setuid: Operation not permitted
```

But it works if runner is root

```
The real user ID is: 0
The effective user ID is :0
pid=1002The real user ID is: 0
The effective user ID is :1002
```

Anything wrong here?

**UPDATE**

Modify the JNI part to executable c

```
void show_ids (void)
 {
    printf ("The real user ID is: %d\n", getuid());
    printf ("The effective user ID is :%d\n", geteuid());
  }

 int main(void)
 {

    show_ids();
    if (seteuid (1002) < 0) {
      perror ("setuid");
      exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    show_ids();
    return (0);
  }
```

Build it as **root** and run **chmod u+s**

```
-rwsr-xr-x  1 root root 8814 Aug  9 11:44 a.out*
```

Run it as normal user and works

```
./a.out
The real user ID is: 1000
The effective user ID is :0
The real user ID is: 1000
The effective user ID is :1002
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33838678/setuid-failing-operation-not-permitted

Comment: Possible duplicate of [setuid() failing - operation not permitted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33838678/setuid-failing-operation-not-permitted)

Comment: It works well for a pure c program, but failed after modify it to JNI.

Comment: and what I changed is euid but uid

Comment: If you investigate more closely, you should find that this does not work with a pure C program either if the process is not privileged.  See "man seteuid" and search for EPERM.   (This is a good thing.  If a non-privileged program could grant itself privilege, then any logged-in user would be able to write a program to break system access control.)

Comment: @StephenC, yes it need build as root and use chmod u+s on it, otherwise it does not work. The thing is, I did same thing in java but failed

Comment: Well yes. It is working **because** of the u+s and root ownership.  You cannot (should not!!) do that on the `java` command, and doing it on the JAR file won't work. Setting "u+s" on a shell launch script is exceedingly dangerous.  The only way to **safely** make a "setuid to root" Java application is to write a native code launcher, and make the launcher "setuid root".

Comment: @StephenC Create, thanks lot!

Comment: This really looks like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).  What actual problem are you trying to solve by running as another user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason that `seteuid` was not working for you from JNI was that the effective user id for the JVM process was not 0 (root).

You were apparently attempting to make the effective user id by setting the "setuid" bit on your native library.  That won't work.  Similarly, making the JAR file (or a class file) as setuid won't work.  The setuid bit is only meaningful on a executable file; i.e. a file that the *OS itself* knows how to execute.

So how do we implement "setuid root behavior" for a Java program?

- In theory, you could mark the `/usr/bin/java` as setuid to root.  **Don't do that!** If you do that, every Java program you run will be run as root.  That would be bad.
- In theory, you could write a shell script to launch your application; e.g.

  ```
     #!/bin/sh
     java some.pkg.Main "$@"
  ```

  and mark the script as setuid to root.  **Don't do that!** Setuid shell scripts are a security risk.  (On some versions of Linux / UNIX the setuid bit is not respected for shell scripts anyway.)

The solution is to write a custom JVM launcher in native code, compile and link it, and make the launcher executable setuid.  Note that the launcher must be written *very carefully* to project against someone subverting it.   For example:

- It should ignore CLASSPATH environment variable, and should not allow the classpath to be supplied any other way.
- It should not take a user-supplied JAR file as a parameter.
- It should take care that the user can't trick it into running the wrong Java code by interfering with the path to the JAR file.
- And other things ... that I haven't thought of!

In fact, it is probably safer to run the Java application as a privileged user ... and not rely on "setuid root" at all.

Comment: See also [chroot “jail” - what is it and how do I use it?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/105/chroot-jail-what-is-it-and-how-do-i-use-it)